# Bot saying only one word in string

Tags: discord, bots, discord.py

As in title. I'm trying to get my bot to send an announcement, without having to use "" to capture the whole sentence. [What the hell do you mean?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lgSE.png)

Here's my code:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@discord.ext.commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def announce(ctx, message : str):
    if message == None:
    return
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title='yBot  |  ANNOUNCEMENT', description='', color= 0xFF0000)
        embed.add_field(name="ANNOUNCEMENT: ", value="{}".format(message))
        embed.set_footer(text="© 2020 - Powered by yanuu ;k#2137")
        await ctx.send("||@everyone||")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in the way you defined the command it self. It should be with a `*` so that it will take everything after

```py
async def announce(ctx,*, message : str):
```

Have a look at this [doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters)

Comment: Worked for me, Thanks!